# Is it possible to add a key to a value that does not have a key in JSON?

Tags: json

I have a JSON without a key but just a value. Is it possible to add a key to it using React?

Here I have the `and` hanging without a key. How do I add a key to it, so that it's easier to read? I looked at *JSON.Stringify* and checked the **replacer** but it does not let me do it. **delete** also does not let me do it.

```
{
    "sample": [
        {
            "id": "r-1",
            "name": "sam"
        },
        "and",
        {
            "id": "r-2",
            "name": "jerry"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Do you actually have a JSON string, or do you have a JavaScript object? You wouldn't use React for this unless it's a state property. You'd just use raw JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing objects and arrays. The "key" with the string `and` as a value isn't a key. It's an array element (the value of the `sample` property is an array). It can't *have* a key unless you convert it from a string to an object, like the array elements before and after it, which are objects.

The structure of the array on the `sample` object property looks like this:

```
object | string | object
```

If you're ok changing your data from a string to an object, just replace the second array element (index 1) in the `sample` property with a new object:

```js
const myObj = {
  "sample": [{
      "id": "r-1",
      "name": "sam"
    },
    "and",
    {
      "id": "r-2",
      "name": "jerry"
    }
  ]
}

myObj.sample[1] = {
  newKey: myObj.sample[1]
};

console.log(myObj);
```

Comment: Ah, yes.. reading your answer, I think i need to read more about this and have gotten confused between the two.